# Cross Origin Resource Sharing question

Tags: http, rest, crossdomain

I have some mockup html/javascript on my desktop, I made an ajax GET call to:

http://www.bungie.net/platform/Destiny/TigerPSN/Account/4611686018429149347/Character/2305843009215132906/Activities/

and got back 200 OK with results. But I noticed that the response's accept-header was:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.bungie.net  when using a proxy (and it was null when using Firefox).

In either case, why didn't this throw an cross origin resource sharing error? The response header didn't say *, so technically this should fail because my desktop is not on the bungie.net domain. Why did it succeed?

Thanks so much!

Comment: How are you hosting your local code? If it's just as a direct file path into your browser, it may ignore SOP as you've not got an origin. Keep in mind that the SOP for CORS is browser-enforced, not server-enforced.